# Analyze HTTP-header before body is transmitted in apache tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

Is it possible to analyze the header of a HTTP-(POST)-Request before the body is transmitted?

I would like to send an error to a client if the file he is trying to upload via an HTTP-POST is to large to handle for the server. To improve the user experience (and safe traffic) I would prefer to send the error response before he uploads the whole file, by analyzing the *content-length-header.*

I thought about implementing a *javax.servlet.filter* like this:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
   if (request.getContentLength() > MAX_DOCUMENT_SIZE) {
          ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
          Map<String, Object> jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
          jsonMap.put("messageCode", 1234);
          jsonMap.put("messageDescription", "error message");

          response.reset();
          response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE);
          jsonMapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), jsonMap);
          return;
       }
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

but I am not sure if the tomcat is able to analyze the headers before the hole request was transmitted.

EDIT: curl

```
> CONNECT myserver.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: myserver.com:443
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> user-agent: my-test
>
< HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established
<
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
* Server certificate: myserver.com
> POST /uploads HTTP/1.1
> Host: myserver
> Accept: */*
> user-agent: my-test
> Content-Length: 51951089
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Tue, 01 Sep 2015 09:49:01 GMT
* Server WEB is not blacklisted
< Server: WEB
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000 ; includeSubDomains
< Cache-Control: private
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 0
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Connection: close
<
```

Comment: You should definitely try that

Comment: Yes it should work. Remember to set `Connection: close` in response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and I am actually doing this in Tomcat 6. I have not tried a `Filter` but a Tomcat-specific `Valve`. If this solution works as a `Vavle`, feel free to port it to a `Filter`.

Have Tomcat to invoke your valve. Your demo code looks just the way it should look, make sure that you send a `400` (or better `413`) to indicate that the input is not appropriate. You may close the connection too. Now here comes the very important part: to make this work, the client has to `POST` or `PUT` the request, additionally the client **must** send a `Expect: 100-continue` header. The server will analyze all incoming headers and signal the client that the request is inappropriate. With that, the client will receive a `400` (or better `413`) before it sends off its payload (request will be aborted). You'll exchange headers only and save resources. But beware, your clients must properly implement `Expect: 100-continue`. .NET clients don't. I would strongly recommend to verify the proper working of your valve with `curl` because it does the stuff right. If you'd like to see wire headers for this, no problem.

Caveat: your content length limit won't work if the client streams its payload in chunks.

Comment: I works, but I encountered a strange phenomenon: When sending a huge file via curl, it gets rejected with 413 although the content-length-header does not exceed the limit I have defined.

Comment: Please run `curl` with `--verbose` and show the logs. I would also recommend to add some `log.debug()` to your valve with remote address and port, as well as the header. This will help to find your problem.

Comment: ok, I figured out the content-length problem was some kind of curl bug. But still, there is some strange behavior: The result is not 413 as expected, but 404. Tomcat's access.log shows, that `GET /apache-error/HTTP_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE.html.var HTTP/1.1" 404` is called. Any idea?

Comment: @woezelmann Can you share `access.log` portion and `curl` verbose log.

Comment: I edited my post. access.log only shows the line in the comment above.

Comment: @woezelmann Your problem is that you did not add a servlet mapping for `/uploads`. Therefore, Tomcat first checks for a mapping and then invokes your valve. Moreover, the provide content type does not make sense. You are uploading binary files and not form fields.

Comment: @Michael-O i have same requirement so did i need to use RequestFilterValve?

Comment: @navy Please rephrase your requirement.

Comment: @Michael-O  i am implementing a file server where i need to check header before receiving file data . Header authentication is done by checking a token in header. So i create a valve which extends RequestFilterValve and inside invoke(Request request, Response response) method i check token and based on that process and deny the request. But its still take file data with request

Comment: @navy, Create a new SO question and point me to that. Also include the curl verbose output.

Answer (score 0):

You write a java script function and bind it onchange event on input type="file" files[0].size will give u size of the file.So u can check if it is uploadable.

Thx

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that it's a REST-API. I have no control over the client code.